# Load image after the json is parsed and presented

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage

i would like to know how to load an image without delaying the user.

I have been trying to load an image from an url, after the view appear and all the user info is showed, so when the user clicks a button the view is showed without any delay.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any solution you come up with is going to require loading your images asynchronously (i.e. in the background).  I'd recommend starting a background thread to load the image as soon as you get the URL from your JSON, so then it'll be ready when the user clicks on the button to display it.

I also recommend doing some caching, so previously downloaded images are already "on disk" and don't need to come over the network to be displayed.

[Here's a sample project I did that displays how to load (and cache) images from URL's](http://github.com/dautermann/ViewPicturesFromWeb).  It's not JSON, but it might help you out.

Comment: could you please tell me how can I create the background thread or any async way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use NSURLConnection to do the downloading:

```
NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue* q = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:q
   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *resp, NSData *d, NSError *err) {
       if (d) {
           UIImage* im = [UIImage imageWithData:d];
           // do something with the image
       }
   }];
```

The download happens on a background thread, so the user is not delayed and (most important) the main thread is not blocked; but once the download is complete, the completion handler happens on the main thread so it is now safe to stick the image into your interface or set a property to it or whatever.

Comment: That code, and much more detail, including some elaborate stuff about downloading and caching images, comes from my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch37.html#_http_requests